# Go into an "if" statement based on unique values

Tags: java

Having a bit of an issue. Trying to make a simple if statement where by it filters out previous values that have gone through the if statement.

getDBQueueID passes through the following integers:

> 1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,10

and I want only the unique values to go into that 'if' statement.

Ideally do not want an array as those number will exceed the millions.

Snippet code:

```
public int DBQueueID;
public int prevQueueNumber=0;

if(getDBQueueID()>0 && prevQueueNumber!=getDBQueueID())
    {
        addCall(getDBQueueID());
        prevQueueNumber = getDBQueueID();   
    }
```

Comment: put the data in a Set collection.

Answer (score 2):

If you can order the numbers that "getDBQueueID" passes into the if statement, you can just check each time in the if statement that the current number is greater than the previous.  Like so..

```
public int DBQueueID;
public int prevQueueNumber=0;

while(getDBQueueID()>0 && getDBQueueID() > prevQueueNumber)
    {
        addCall(getDBQueueID());
        prevQueueNumber = getDBQueueID();   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Isiva and Luke - thanks, set Collection worked perfectly as did your solution